# How can I pass a constant to a Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl, reference, constants, subroutine

I have got as follows:

```
 use constant ABC => ('one', 'two', 'three');
```

and I want to pass this constant to `variations_with_repetition(\@data, $k)` subroutine as `@data`.

How should I do that?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `use constant ABC => ['one', 'two', 'three'];`? `[ ABC ]` will create a new anonymous array each time you use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `[]` operator to convert a list to an ARRAY reference:

```
variations_with_repetition( [ABC] , $k );
```